# How to call a phtml file in category view

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating a block in catalog.xml like this

```
<block type="catalog/category_sidebar_all" name="category_sidebar_all" as="category_sidebar_all" template="catalog/category/sidebar/all.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

I am calling the block like this in category/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_sidebar_all'); ?>
```

Nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<your_layout_handle>  //<catalog_category_view> for exemple
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/category_sidebar_all" name="category_sidebar_all" as="category_sidebar_all" template="catalog/category/sidebar/all.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

You call it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('category_sidebar_all') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply  but this did not work as well.

Comment: It's not possible, in wich xml are you added the code ? what is the error ? the xml and the call are correct, maybe you are missing in your type block